# Detect if Ajax Request had failed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

How can I detect whether an Ajax request failed to load a file.

**Here is my code for reference**:

```
var pro = undefined;
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        pro = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","data.json",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

***Please, no jQuery.***

Thanks!

Comment: No jQuery?   I've a good mind to down vote you!

Comment: @SteveWellens Why a down vote? I just want to avoid using jQuery.

Comment: Avoiding jQuery is like avoiding the wheel.  jQuery helps you.  (I was kidding, I didn't down vote you).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can check if the http status is 500 or more than 500 which means an error occurred in the request http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error

```
 if (xmlhttp.status >= 500){
    alert('error');
 }
```

**NOTE**: you can also consider other http status numbers as you like

Comment: @zerkms Isn't a 503 (Service Unavailable) technically an error?

Comment: @Progo: it is. The original answer was `xmlhttp.status == 500` which didn't include `503` and was modified afterwards

Comment: @zerkms Oh, sorry, i didn't know that. :)

Comment: @zerkms sorry for not notifying anyone for the changes i made =)

Answer (score 2):

`onerror` callback should be used for handling error, like this:

```
xmlhttp.onerror = function onError(e) {
    alert("Error " + e.target.status + " occurred while receiving the document.");
}
```

As far as I know, jQuery library also uses this method. Not sure which all browsers support this, but this surely works in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is use a global variable I name 'boomerang' (witty I know)

so when you send the request out make boomerang=1 and then on its success make boomerang=0

then at some appropriate time after you send the request out then you can just check if boomerang =1 or =0

Comment: So in your code you never deal with more than 1 request?

Comment: @zerkms no if I have multiple or a chance of multiple requests then everytime one goes out I do boomerang++ and on success boomerang--. so im computing the balance of requests sent out versus those that have returned

Comment: assuming that after *several* requests have been sent and as a result `boomerang == 5`. How helpful is it? You still have no idea which failed. So you cannot handle it properly. Btw, "appropriate time" is a weird term.

Comment: in the situation I had it did not matter which request was lost/failed, we only needed to know if any failed. also we had an appropriate time, if within a 10second interval there were any lost/failed requests we just had to log it

Answer (score 1):

you need to check the status code- 4xx and 5xx codes are errors.

here's a list of codes:  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 0):

You won't need much more. Do something in the else clause other than the comment.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        pro = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    } else {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
            // Something failed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if the http status is 302? or not 200? its not a failure though

Comment: You shouldn't be getting anything that isn't 200 in the 200 range. And 302 tells the request object that there is more to handle. Anything else will be processed as a failure.

Comment: anything less than 400 *can* be considered fine.  300 range is a redirect, which you can (try to) follow if you care, but should generally be considered successful (an http->https load balancers might give a 302 to a page that 500s, so you need to know the behavior of your url target).