# javascript post/get request readystate catch error

Tags: javascript

How to catch error during `post` request in javascript? I know if `readyState == 4` means request is complete and if `status==200` means the request is successful. The idea is to show a message when the post request fails say internet connection fails or wrong value.

Currently I have something like this, the modal is working okay when its

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
            hideToolbar();
            console.log('Saving successful.');
        } else if(xhttp.status == "failed"){
            console.log('Sorry there is a problem.');
        }
    };
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        "name":"name",
        "definition":diagramData
    });
    xhttp.send(data);
```

Comment: You can check for the other status codes and readystates for error handling, or run a try/catch block

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if Ajax Request had failed in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925803/detect-if-ajax-request-had-failed-in-javascript)

Comment: if you're listening to `.onload` you don't need to check readyState

Comment: since you seem to use JQuery, why don't you use JQuery.ajax()

Comment: @maioman I'm using onreadystate change.

Comment: @C.Champagne I'm not using jquery but vanilla js.

Comment: @nCore what is this `$("#myModal").modal();` then?

Comment: @Maxx oh that was just a dummy modal which won't be used. but the request is done in vanilla js not ajax.post

Comment: Edited my original post.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you'd want to wrap this in an `xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(...` so this only triggers when a response is got. Maybe you just cut out the code in the middle of that, but still good to mention.

Second off, it's usually not great to do a catch-all for a fail on statuses other than 200. Sometimes a server can send a 201,202 and still work okay. I would say to change your `else` statement to an `else if` and explicitly check for `if(xhttp.status >= 400)` for an error.

However, I hate to be the 'just use jQuery' guy, but you're already using it. jQuery greatly simplifies AJAX calls and even provides a built-in promise for the results. You could accomplish the above like this:

```
$.post('http://my-url.com', {my: 'data'}).done(function(response) {
    hideToolbar();
    $("#myModal").modal();
    })
    .error(function(error) {
    console.log('did not work because of', error)});
```

Comment: $("#modal") won't be use and I want to stay in vanilla js for this request.